# AngularJS Multi-Level Default Routes

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

In AngularJS, I wanted to send all my routes to a single controller - so I figured - why set up routing at all?

It seems simpler to get route information with `$window.location.pathname.split("/");`

At first, this looked like a good plan:

- 'mysite.com' worked
- 'mysite.com/' worked
- 'mysite.com/home' worked

But when I try to do a 2-level or a 3-level route:

- 'mysite.com/team/my-name'
- 'mysite.com/blog/post/my-post'

Angular crashes saying:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Why isn't Angular default routing OK with multi-level routes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Angular Router is just not meant for that (yet).  Try the [UI Router](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router) it will do what you are expecting.